# Array prints data correctly but query shows only half

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having a very very strange issue here. I am having data inside of an array in php. I want for each item that the array has to query the database and get results back. It only shows me specific results and not everything.

My code:

```
foreach($my as $k=> $v){
    //echo "Key: ". $k . " Value: " . $v . "<br/>";
    $sql2 = "SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = '$v' ";
    $res2 = mysql_command($sql2);
    echo $sql2 . "<br/>";
    $rowA = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
    //echo "<strong>Alternative: </strong>" . $v. "<strong> Auto Alternative: </strong>" . $rowA['column10'] . "<br/>";

}
echo '</table>';
echo "<pre>";
print_r($my);
echo "</pre>";
```

In the browser the result if i echo the query and Key: and value is this:

```
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = 'Villetta La Canoa' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Casa Immerso nel Verde' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' La Rosetta' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = 'Agriturismo La Nonna' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Villetta Cassiopeia' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' La Rosetta' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = 'Ca Gianca 2' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Villetta Teresa' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Appartamento Pinamare' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Casa del Principe' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = 'Ca Gianca 2' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Villetta Teresa' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Appartamento Pinamare' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Casa del Principe' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = 'Ca Gianca 2' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Villetta Teresa' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Appartamento Pinamare' 
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Casa del Principe'
```

The Key,Value is :

```
Key: 0 Value: Villetta La Canoa
Key: 1 Value: Casa Immerso nel Verde
Key: 2 Value: La Rosetta
Key: 3 Value: Agriturismo La Nonna
Key: 4 Value: Villetta Cassiopeia
Key: 5 Value: La Rosetta
Key: 6 Value: Ca Gianca 2
Key: 7 Value: Villetta Teresa
Key: 8 Value: Appartamento Pinamare
Key: 9 Value: Casa del Principe
Key: 10 Value: Ca Gianca 2
Key: 11 Value: Villetta Teresa
Key: 12 Value: Appartamento Pinamare
Key: 13 Value: Casa del Principe
Key: 14 Value: Ca Gianca 2
Key: 15 Value: Villetta Teresa
Key: 16 Value: Appartamento Pinamare
Key: 17 Value: Casa del Principe
```

and what i get is:

```
Alternative: Villetta La Canoa Auto Alternative: Villa Ronchi, Casa Ciserai, Villino Torretta, Casa Bianca
Alternative: Casa Immerso nel Verde Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: La Rosetta Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Agriturismo La Nonna Auto Alternative: Agriturismo Antico Granaio, Casa Ciserai, Villa Ronchi, La Rosetta
Alternative: Villetta Cassiopeia Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: La Rosetta Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Ca Gianca 2 Auto Alternative: Ca Gianca 1, La Vigna 2, Villetta Teresa
Alternative: Villetta Teresa Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Appartamento Pinamare Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Casa del Principe Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Ca Gianca 2 Auto Alternative: Ca Gianca 1, La Vigna 2, Villetta Teresa
Alternative: Villetta Teresa Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Appartamento Pinamare Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Casa del Principe Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Ca Gianca 2 Auto Alternative: Ca Gianca 1, La Vigna 2, Villetta Teresa
Alternative: Villetta Teresa Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Appartamento Pinamare Auto Alternative: 
Alternative: Casa del Principe Auto Alternative:
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Comment: Hello, first of all a cople of tips, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should change to `mysqli` or `PDO ` and you should give the db columns more descripive names, it can be a nightmare to maintain or understand that code :)

Comment: it show u `SELECT column10`, not `SELECT *` ???

Comment: What on earth is `mysql_command` ?

Comment: Asur i know its deprecated but lets say that my server runs PHP 5.2, devpro i only want to display this field. @Hanky Panky mysql_command is a custom method that gets the query and returns data for me. But the important part is that i execute query right, and still get half data i want

Comment: I have answered your *important point* already :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my point of view you may have to trim $v to be sure there are no white spaces at the start and end of string.

```
foreach($my as $k=> $v){
   $v = trim($v);
```

Also you should try the 'LIKE' operator instead of '='. Perhaps add '%' to $v.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 LIKE '%{$v}%'";
```

Comment: Don't mind this opinion but this is just a workaround to please your eyes and see your code fixed. Problem is that why is that extra space there in the first place? If you should not be storing that extra space then why are you storing it and then trimming it at the end? Someday that could lead to unexpected results. Trimming an incorrectly formatted string just to get things going is not a good design solution. Fix the code which is mistakenly storing extra spaces in the database.

Comment: @BRG As Hanky said this is a quick solution to your code. Listen to his advice and try to remove the spaces from the source.

Comment: the thing is that is not individual item but the are separated by comma and i explode them in order to separate them. so that is why the blank spaces occured. because of this: `$similar[]= explode(",", $row['3']);`

Comment: i should have done this: `$similar[]= explode(", ", $row['3']);` and i would not need trim.

Answer (score 3):

What on earth is `mysql_command`? I'm sure its a typo and you meant `mysql_query` (Alas even for that :-/)

And you dont get results for some because of an extra space behind some strings like this one

```
SELECT column10 FROM `table` WHERE column1 = ' Casa Immerso nel Verde' 
                                              ^
```

Your sample data confirms this. The only results you have no alternatives for are the ones that have that extra space.